# Sort different sized arrays in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have 2 np.array objects

```
non_direct_start = [5 100]
```

and

```
direct_start = [1 9 105]
```

and I want to or them in ascending order
like

```
idx_start =

     [1     5     9   100   105]
```

I've tried to sort these using np.sort but its show the error

```
idx_start = np.sort((non_direct_start, direct_start))

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (2,)
```

Is there any function available to do this?
Or I have to go the Looping way?

Comment: Merge both arrays before sorting.

Comment: Those aren't `np.array` objects, they're plain lists.

Comment: _and I want to or [sic] them in ascending order like_ That’s not just sorting though, right, it looks like you combined the 2 lists.

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.concatenate` to join them into one array, then `np.sort`:

```
np.sort(np.concatenate((non_direct_start, direct_start)))
```

Output:

```
array([  1,   5,   9, 100, 105])
```